# errmsg: Model.insertMany is not an object

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build a route in my React app to add many items to a MongoDB at a single time. It is failing with the error message "insertMany is not an object"

Here is my model:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

// author schema
const authorSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema)
```

Here is my route:

```
authorRouter.post('/manyauthors', (req, res, next) => {
  const newAuthor = new Author(req.body)
  newAuthor.insertMany(req.body, (err, savedAuthor) => {
    if(err){
      res.status(500)
      return next(err)
    }
    return res.status(201).send(savedAuthor)
  })
})
```

And here is the raw JSON I am running in through Postman:

```
[
    {"name": "Alice Walker"},
    {"name": "Stephen King"}
]
```

I actually had it working earlier in the day, but accidentally wiped it out. So I know that insertMany is indeed a function. There's just something I'm missing. I'm hoping someone can figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertMany` is indeed a function, but I would suggest calling it a bit differently. I will assume that you need it to insert brand new documents into your collections and not, say, insert a bunch of subdocuments to an existing doc. Here is how to do it:

```
const Author = mongoose.model('Author');
...
...
authorRouter.post('/manyauthors', (req, res, next) => {
  const array_to_insert = req.body.data;
  Author.insertMany(array_to_insert)
    .then(r => {
        res.status(201).send(r)
     })
     .catch(r => {
        res.status(400).send("Something went wrong")
     })
})
```

This assumes that your body looks like this:

```
{data: [
    {"name": "Alice Walker"},
    {"name": "Stephen King"}
]}
```

Comment: Many thanks, CodeMonkey, you earned your bananas today. 

While the solution you proposed did not work for me (the JSON was rejected), you did put me onto the right path. Creating a constant from req.body, and using that constant as the argument both for instantiating the instance of Author, and as the first argument of the insertMany function overcame whatever problem I was having.

```
// Add many authors
authorRouter.post('/manyauthors', (req, res, next) => {
  const Authors = req.body
  const newAuthor = new Author(Authors)
  Author.insertMany(Authors, (err, savedAuthor) ,,,